# php email sender code dose not work properly

Tags: php, email, post, sender

can you please tell anybody what is the error this my code. this code working properly but first time i click the send button after send message to my email. but second time i don't need to click the send button only i do refresh my page then message send automatically to my email. what's the problem?

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) { 

$name = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message) )

{
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Regoora Message Center"; 
         $message1 = "Customer Name :".$name."
                    Customer Email :".$email." 
                    Customer Phone :".$phone." 
                    Customer interested :".$interested ." 
                    Customer message :".$message." ";
        mail("email@example.com",$subject,$message1); 
        $mess = "Successfully sent your inquiry";
    }
    else{



$mess = 'We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.';     




}}
```

Comment: Use a conditional statement with a named submit button and do a redirect with a header. Plus, `$from` is a stray variable, so add that in your headers.

Comment: Here => http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php plus you can also make use of sessions and tokens which will prevent resubmissions.

Answer (score 0):

If your code worked properly the first time, it is because it works fine. The second time you just refreshed the page and it sent another email because 'Refresh' will always repeat your last action. If you last action was 'Send Email', refreshing the page will try to resend the email.

What you could do to avoid that is, after sending, click on the address bar (http://localhost/xxxx) and press enter. It will reset the page.

Comment: What about other people than the OP? They're not going to follow that. This won't work.

Comment: You have many option to avoid people resending the email. The first option would be to do `unset($_POST['send']);` after sending the email. Second option would be to redirect the user to another page.